# How to automate bar chart labels

Tags: r

I would like data labels to appear at the end of each bar, with one space between the label and the end of the bar. I would like the labels to be expressed as percents. Please note, the graph was constructed using raw numbers, not percentage values. I would like the solution to this problem to be in base R. Answers to similar prior questions have not worked for me.

```
 table(cont$cont9) # 1=0, 2=0,3=2, 4=2, 5=21
 #1=0%, 2=0%,3=8%, 4=8%, 5=84%

 par(mar=c(0, 5, 0, 2.1))
 H <- c(0, 0, 2, 2, 21) # Create the data for the chart, cont3.#
 M <- c("Very Low", "Low", "Medium", "High", "Very High")

 barplot(H, col =c("slategray1", "slategray1","slategray1",
              "slategray1", "steelblue3"), 
    horiz = TRUE, 
    family="Arial", border = NA, names.arg = M, 
    xlim = range(0,100), ylim = range(0, 0.08), 
    axes = FALSE, width = 0.01, las=1, xaxt='n')
```

I would like percentage data labels at the end of each bar. With the solution in base R.

Answer (score 1):

To do what the question asks for, keep the return value of `barplot` and use it as the `y` coordinates of the labels. The return value is:

> A numeric vector (or matrix, when beside = TRUE), say mp, giving the
>   coordinates of all the bar midpoints drawn, useful for adding to the
>   graph.

The `x` coordinates are the plotted values, with the position adjusted, `pos = 4`.
In the code that follows, I start by also keeping the return value of the call to `par`. This is a general purpose good habit. When done plotting, reset the defaults as they were.

```
op <- par(mar=c(0, 5, 0, 2.1))

bp <- barplot(H, col =c("slategray1", "slategray1","slategray1",
              "slategray1", "steelblue3"), 
    horiz = TRUE, 
    family = "Arial", border = NA, names.arg = M, 
    xlim = range(0,100), ylim = range(0, 0.08), 
    axes = FALSE, width = 0.01, las=1, xaxt='n')
text(H, bp, labels = H/sum(H), pos = 4)

par(op)
```

[image]

**Note:**

Though I have not change it, I find

```
xlim = c(0, 30), ylim = c(0, 0.08),
```

more natural.

- It uses `c`, not `range`.
- The `xlim` values agree with `range(H)`.

Comment: Thanks! So, with this solution, is it possible to add a % sign at the end of the label?

Comment: Try `labels = scales::percent(H/sum(H))`. This function in package `scales` multiplies by 100 and appends the `%` sign without the need to tamper with the numbers, it's for display purposes only.

Comment: Is there a way to get the percents rounded to the nearest whole number?

Comment: @freeazabird Yes, there is. Set argument `accuracy = 1`.